Kentico Cache Dependencies not triggering cache clearance
I generate a cache and it's dependencies like so:

But when I make changes to documentid 40070 the cache doesn't clear.
What I've troubleshooted:

Updated to latest hotfix v13.0.167
Installed xperience-enhanced-webfarmname-provider to ensure unique web farm names
Checked licence (ok and has unlimited web farms allowed)
Restarted web farms
Ensure web farms are healthy and have no tasks pending
Check if content updated in page builder mode (it is).
Ensure https and valid cert (RapidSSL TLS RSA CA G1) for both front and back end

Is there anything else I'm missing?
Thanks,
Rory

How are you generating that cache key in code?  Typically when you run a document query it will do this already for you so there'd be no need to create your own key.  My guess is you're not properly generating your key properly which is why the cache is not cleared.

@BrendenKehren I was using Trevor Fayas's baseline's CacheDependencyKeysBuilder.  But now I see that it is no longer supported so that must be the issue.

YOu may want to check the Nuget package and see if you're on the latest for that version.  It may help resolve an issue.  You can also reach out to Trevor, he may be able to help
